# Magento 2 get custom module image url from backend

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, url, image

I used

```
<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Vendor_Module::images/demo.jpg'); ?>
<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('Vendor_Module::images/demo.jpg'); ?>
```

But it's working only frontend, I want it in adminhtml block file.

I used this in renderer column of grid
File:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Renderer;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject;

class FileIcon extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer
{

    public function render(DataObject $row)
    {

        echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Vendor_Module::images/demo.jpg');
        echo $block->getViewFileUrl('Vendor_Module::images/demo.jpg');

        exit;
        //return $file;;

    }
}
```

Comment: try with $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl().'pub/static/frontend/Namespace/Modulename/en_US/images/demo.jpg';

Comment: This works only when image available in static folder also this is not right way to get url.

Comment: `Vendor_Module` is your custom module name.

Comment: Did you try only with `echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Vendor_Module::images/demo.jpg');`?

Comment: See my updated answer. We can try with `$this->getViewFileUrl('Vendor_Module::images/demo.jpg');`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `\Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository` class

```
protected $_assetRepo;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_assetRepo = $assetRepo;
    ...
}
```

Now, you can get image URL by

```
echo $this->_assetRepo->getUrl("Vendor_Module::images/demo.jpg");
```

Comment: It doesn't work on my side, when I inspect my image, I see this: <img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/pub/static/version1510235195/frontend/Myvendor/mytheme/zh_Hans_CN/Magento_Theme/images/ad2.jpg" style="display: none !important;">

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at the Magento Marketplace module:

vendor/magento/module-marketplace/view/adminhtml/templates/index.phtml

```
$block->getViewFileUrl('Magento_Marketplace::partners/images/magento-connect.png');
```

The image is `vendor/magento/module-marketplace/view/adminhtml/web/partners/images/magento-connect.png`

Our image should be under `web`:

`view/adminhtml/web/images/demo.jpg`

Try to get with the module prefix in your template:

```
<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('Your_Module::images/demo.jpg'); ?>
```

Remember to clear Magento Cache and may need to delete `view_preprocessed` folder.

**[EDIT]**

In your case, you can try with

```
$this->getViewFileUrl('Vendor_Module::images/image-demo.jpg');
```

Comment: yes I have already image in adminhtml/web folder but it's seems like $this->getViewFileUrl() or $block->getViewFileUrl() not working

Comment: I have tested. I'm pretty sure it will work, did you try to echo and run static content deploy content?

Comment: Check now I edited question with file where I try to get URL.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers to this question are correct, but may partially not correct or incomplete if still you can not get the image to show on the Backend.

If you have tried any of these solutions and is not working try this:

1) Make sure you have got the files you want to load in your **custom Module directory** like this:
`Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/images/mage.jpg` or and `Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/mage.js`

2) Then in your `block`

```
public function __construct(        
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $moduleAssetDir,        
        array $data = []
    ) {

        $this->moduleAssetDir = $moduleAssetDir;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
```

You can then call the files like shown below:

```
$MageImage = $this->moduleAssetDir->getUrl("Vendor_Module::images/mage.jpg");
     $JsMage = $this->moduleAssetDir->getUrl("Vendor_Module::js/mage.js");
```

3) Then run this commandline

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

It will cause no harm if you choose to run this long line instead

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento indexer:reindex && php bin/magento cache:flush && php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Out of curiosity:

After upgrade check your pub directory assuming one of the `locale` is `en_GB` you should have something like this:

```
/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Vendor_Module/images/mage.jpg       

/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Vendor_Module/js/mage.js
```

And rendered some like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="siteUrl/static/version1234567890/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Vendor_Module/js/mage.js"></script>

    <img src="siteUrl/static/version1234567890/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Vendor_Module/images/mage.jpg" />
```